# I have a problem with dockerizing node js app with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

this is my docker-compose codes

```
version: '3'
services:
  mongo:
    container_name: "mongo"
    image: "mongo:4.4.8"
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
  web:
    image: docker-node-mongo
    build: .
    command: "node src/index.js"
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    depends_on:
      - "mongo"
```

and this is my docker file

```
FROM node
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4000
CMD "node" "src/index.js"
```

and this is my connection file

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose")
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://mongo:27017/mongo-test", {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true
    })
```

and this error occur

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
web_1    |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1146:16) {
web_1    |   name: 'MongoNetworkError'
web_1    | }]

I would be thankful if you help me .

Comment: Are you sure that you are actually trying to connect to`mongo:27017`? From the error message, it seems localhost instead. Do you need to rebuild the docker image?

Comment: Oops , thanks for your help , I rebuild it and now it`s ok

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app  # -p create all parent folders
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  web:
    image: docker-node-mongo
    container_name: docker-node-mongo
    build: .  # path to your Dockerfile
    command: nodemon src/app.js # Use nodemon to reload on changes
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app # To enable auto reload on changes
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    depends_on:
      - mongo_db

  mongo_db:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    container_name: mongo_container # Use this in the connection url
    command: mongod -port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --replSet rs0
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongo_storage:/data/db

volumes:
  mongo_storage:
```

#### Connection file

```
 const mongoose = require("mongoose")
 mongoose.connect("mongodb://mongo_container:27017/mongo-test?replicaSet=rs0", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
 })
```

To enable replica set in mongodb,

`docker compose up --build -d` # to build your app in docker

`docker exec -it mongo_db mongo` # to enter in the mongo shell in docker

`rs.initiate({ _id: "rs0", version: 1, members: [{ _id: 0, host : "mongo_db:27017" }] })`

Please use this as a pointer to how to set up Node and MongoDB with Docker.